# Oracle to psql inquiry using shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, psql

Can someone help me convert this to psql? i'm using shell script for this.

```
   options (silent = (header,feedback), errors = 999999999)
load data
infile "stat.dat"
"str '\n'"
append into table DT.DETAIL_STAT
fields terminated by '|'
trailing nullcols
(
SCAN_DT "TO_DATE(:SCAN_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy')",                                                                                                                   
SCAN_TM "TO_DATE(:SCAN_TM, 'HH24:MI:SS ')",                                                                                                                  
SCAN_NBR,                                                                                                                                                    
SCANNED_NBR_TYP_CD,
UPC_ID,                                                                                                                                                      
PROMO_IND_CD,                                                                                                                                                
EXPRESS_PROC_IND,                                                                                                                                            
SCAN_TYP_CD,                                                                                                                                                 
USER_INITIAL_ID,                                                                                                                                             
RLSE_DTE "TO_DATE(:RLSE_DTE, 'mm/dd/yyyy')",                                                                                                                 
RLSE_TM "TO_DATE(:RLSE_TM, 'HH24:MI:SS')"
)
```

I've tried to use copy but having error on the ones with date and time
here is the content of the file

```
09/21/2020|10:58:34|88570294      | |0| | |O|   |09/21/2020|11.06.31

09/21/2020|10:58:34|88630062      | |0| | |O|   |09/21/2020|11.06.31

09/21/2020|10:58:34|001853724148  |U|1853724148|N|Y|O|   |09/21/2020|11.06.31
```

Comment: What's to convert? That looks like the contents of some control file, not executable code.  It looks like a control file for sqlldr.

Comment: There is too little detail in your question. What exactly did you do in PostgreSQL? Based on your vague description of the error you got, I'd suggest setting `datestyle='MDY'`.

Comment: Yes its an sqlldr, I want to know how to do this in psql/postgresql? I have use copy command but having error on the field for date and time